# Label Areas in Python Matplotlib stackplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, stacked-chart, stacked-area-chart

I would like to generate labels inside the areas of a matplotlib stackplot. I would settle for labeling a line used to bound the area. Consider the example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fnx = lambda : np.random.randint(5, 50, 10)
x = np.arange(10)
y1, y2, y3 = fnx(), fnx(), fnx()
areaLabels=['area1','area2','area3']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stackplot(x, y1, y2, y3)
plt.show()
```

This produces:[image]

But I would like to produce something like this:

[image]

The matplotlib contour plots have this type of labeling functionality (though the lines are labeled in the case of the contour plot).

Any help (or even redirection to a post I might have missed) is appreciated.

Comment: Newcomers to this question may be confused because [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.stackplot) suggests that labels are supported, but this [appears to be a lie](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1943). I get this error: `AttributeError: Unknown property labels`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, heuristics. Something like this?:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

length = 10
fnx = lambda : np.random.randint(5, 50, length)
x = np.arange(length)
y1, y2, y3 = fnx(), fnx(), fnx()
areaLabels=['area1','area2','area3']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stackplot(x, y1, y2, y3)

loc = y1.argmax()
ax.text(loc, y1[loc]*0.25, areaLabels[0])

loc = y2.argmax()
ax.text(loc, y1[loc] + y2[loc]*0.33, areaLabels[1])

loc = y3.argmax()
ax.text(loc, y1[loc] + y2[loc] + y3[loc]*0.75, areaLabels[2]) 

plt.show()
```

which in test runs is okayish:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Finding the best `loc` could be fancier -- maybe one wants the `x_n, x_(n+1)` with the highest average value.

Comment: very clever. What I like about this is that it has the potential to be applied in a loop for an arbitrary number of labels. And even if it isn't perfect, I find your chart easier to quickly interpret than a comparable chart with a color key--especially when stacking >10 plots.

Comment: There are plots you can't label this way -- if area2 was all tiny, or if the values leapt up and down so there wasn't much horizontal area. It could maybe be a little clearer if the area colors were tied to the text colors somehow (text bordered with area color?).

Comment: yeah, `loc` should be defined in a loop for an arbitrary series of y?. Left as an exercise for the reader!