# Labels (annotate) in pandas area plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Is it possible to put data labels (values) in pandas/matplotlib stacked area charts?

In stacked bar plots, I use the below

```
for label in yrplot.patches:
    yrplot.annotate(label.get_height(), (label.get_x()+label.get_width()/2.,label.get_y()+label.get_height()/2.),
                 ha='center', va='center', xytext=(0, 1), 
                 textcoords='offset points')
```

Below is how I am plotting the stacked area chart

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

yrplot = yrly_perc_df.plot(x='year', y=prod, kind='area', stacked=True, figsize=(15,10), color = areacolors)

yrplot.set_ylabel('share')
yrplot.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0,0.5))
```

[image: Snippet of the stacked area chart for percentage share plotted using above code]

Any leads would be much appreciated. To state my want, it is something similar to **[this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ejMG1DCvEsBOIyMdXvcwV_3hukqbbynQ/view?usp=sharing)** image but in a stacked area chart (data labels along the plot, similar to the first code in the question).

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I want the yearly percentage values on the chart, like in bar charts' annotate. Is it possible in area charts?

Comment: Does this serve your needs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573869/label-areas-in-python-matplotlib-stackplot

Comment: @Bazingaa No, this is not what I actually want. My want is something similar to [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ejMG1DCvEsBOIyMdXvcwV_3hukqbbynQ/view?usp=sharing) but in a stacked area chart.

Comment: Link not working. Also you should try to post in the first place what you want so as to have more chances of getting an answer.

Comment: The title of you question should not say 'area plot' then. What you want is a bar plot.

Comment: @Bazingaa I want something similar to that. but in a stacked area chart, not a bar chart. I can do that in a stacked bar chart, but need help to do the same in a stacked area chart

Comment: @samkart you should really include your desired result in your question. I'm not opening your google documents! Also: Minimum working example?

Comment: Doesn't that make the questions long to read. Also, my want is to get the yearly data labels (%age values) for each 'prod' on the chart. The one I tried to do is there in my question. That's how I started my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The annotations can be manually added to the stacked area chart, using the cumulative sum of the values to compute the y positions of the labels. Also, I suggest not to draw the annotation if the height of the stack is very small.

```
rs = np.random.RandomState(12)
values = np.abs(rs.randn(12, 4).cumsum(axis=0))
dates = pd.date_range("1 1 2016", periods=12, freq="M")
data = pd.DataFrame(values, dates, columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
ax = data.plot(kind='area', stacked=True)
ax.set_ylabel('value')
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0,0.5))

for x1 in data.index:
    # Y positions are given by the cumulative sum of the values, plus half of the height of the specific stack
    yCenteredS = data.loc[x1].cumsum()
    yCenteredS = [0.0] + yCenteredS.tolist()
    yCenteredS = [y + (yCenteredS[i+1] - y)/2. for i, y in enumerate(yCenteredS[:-1])]
    # Draw the values as annotations
    labels = pd.DataFrame(data={'y':yCenteredS, 'value':data.loc[x1].tolist()})
    # Don't draw the annotation if the stack is too small
    labels = labels[labels['value'] > 0.5]

    for _, y, value in labels.itertuples():
        ax.annotate('{:.2f}'.format(value), xy=(x1, y), ha='center', va='center',
                    bbox=dict(fc='white', ec='none', alpha=0.2, pad=1),
                    fontweight='heavy', fontsize='small')
```

[image]